# Institutional style for simple documents in CTAN - folder structure

Tags: package-writing, ctan

I developed a very basic style for simple documents for University (https://github.com/baracunatana/docsimplepuj). I'll like to contribute it to CTAN so other people can use it, but this is my first time doing this so I have a questions:

1. I use a jpg image (university logo) that is in my /img folder. I use it with the relative path to the file (see https://github.com/baracunatana/docsimplepuj/blob/aa37cd192344cc4db0e41ee615f693e485fc342b/docsimplepuj.sty#L50) and it works with the files locally in the same folder as the main .tex file. Will this work if the package is installed from CTAN or will I have to create the /img folder every time I want to use my package?
2. I intend to upload it to /macros/latex/contrib. Is this the right folder for this kind of packages?

Since this is my first package, any feedback regarding good practices is appreciated. The package is quite small and simple.

Thanks,

Comment: don't use a img subfolder. Give your logo a unique name and put it beside the style. The ctan people will place your files, if you are unsure simply add a comment when you upload and ask if it is right, they will help you. Check https://ctan.org/help/upload-pkg first.

Comment: Note you can distribute it around your universiuty without putting it on ctan/texlive so distributing it to the whole world, when it is specific to one institution.  You are nissing a lot of `%` from ends of lines and `begin{tabular}{p{1pt}|p{1pt}l}` looks very odd, a table with each column being a paragraph with lines 1pt in length????

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the tip. I'll contact them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the feedback. Is it good practice to put the % at the end of every line? I read about why that is needed, but can't see a case in which they would be needed for my code. Regarding the table, it was a hacky way to control the space before and after the border at the left of the tabular

Comment: not every line no, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat  On the the `p{1pt}`  perhaps for some use-once personal file you might use such a tabular but please don't put such code on ctan and install it on millions of users filesystems, fix up the code before you consider global distribution.